# modify the picture width and height in a content by search webpart display template?

Tags: display-template

I created a custom item display template. This custom item display template is using my custom hover display template. In my hover display template I get a managed property `CustomImage`. When I add this managed property in a div I can see the picture in the hover display template. I would like to set a fixed picture width and height in my hover display template. How can I do this? Code below is not working:

```
<body>
    <div id="Custom_Item_HoverPanel">
<!--#_
        var i = 0;
        var id = ctx.CurrentItem.csr_id;
        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowViewLibrary = !Srch.U.isWebPage(ctx.CurrentItem.FileExtension);
        if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer)
        {
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_FileType = Srch.Res.ct_Folder
        }

        ctx.currentItem_ShowChangedBySnippet = true;

        var publishingImage = $getItemValue(ctx, 'CustomImage');
        var pictureMarkup = Srch.ContentBySearch.getPictureMarkup(publishingImage, 100, 100, ctx.CurrentItem, '', '', '');
_#-->
        <div class="ms-srch-hover-innerContainer ms-srch-hover-standardSize" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.inner) =#_">
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-arrowBorder" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.arrowBorder) =#_"></div>
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-arrow" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.arrow) =#_"></div>
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-content" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.content) =#_" data-displaytemplate="DefaultHoverPanel">
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.header) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-header">
                    _#= ctx.RenderHeader(ctx) =#_
                </div>
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.body) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-body">
                    _#= ctx.RenderBody(ctx) =#_
                </div>  
                    <div style="padding:20px;">_#= pictureMarkup =#_</div>                              
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.actions) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-actions">
                    _#= ctx.RenderFooter(ctx) =#_
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I think the technology `Srch.ContentBySearch.getPictureMarkup` is working only on the search result webpart. I use the content by search webpart.